# How do I save user input data in C#.NET MVC to a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm very much new to using the MVC Pattern but what I'm trying to do is have a user input some numbers and then each time they submit a number it'll be added to a list. However the list gets wiped between button presses, I currently have all the list stuff in the controller.

**Controller**

```
public class NumberController : Controller
{
    List<int> numList = new List<int>();

    // GET: Number
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessNumber(Number number)
    {
        int RNo = number.RNum;
        numList.Add(RNo);
        string sequenceList = "";
        foreach (int num in numList) { sequenceList = sequenceList + ", " + num; }

        ViewBag.Message = "Number " + RNo + " saved successfully!" + " This is your current sequence :" + sequenceList + " A total of " + numList.Count + "numbers.";
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

Then over in the View I have this.

```
@model TechMVC.Models.Number

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessNumber", "Number", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Number</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RNum, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RNum, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RNum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                <p>@ViewBag.Message</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Which comes out looking like this :

[image: Website Version]

I'm not interested in making it look fancy, I'm just still not overly certain of the MVC framework. I get that I've sent Data here from a user to the view and then to the controller but have I also used the model at some point? Should I store the list in the model or in the view?

Comment: Because the web is stateless. Each request to your server initializes a new controller. You need to persist your data somewhere (ideally a database)

Comment: I think the input I'm currently gathering would be overkill for a database, as I want the user to be able to sort their numbers after they've input them. Would that not require a wipe of the DB for each different user?

Comment: Is it feasible to stored your List as a Session Variable?

Comment: I don't think the session is a great idea. How are you planning to keep the values for the subsequent request?

Comment: My original idea was to collect all the user input within the view before sending a request to the controller to handle all the inputs at once, so sort them into a sequence and store this sequence in a DB with the way it was sorted and a sorting time

Comment: If you just want the user to be able to sort their number and you don't want persist the data, then why don't you stored it at client side? Local Storage, Session Storage or Cookies

Comment: I think I'm having a hard time explaining what I want to do. Effectively I just want a user to enter numbers and then I want to sort those numbers and add the sequence to a DB

Comment: @CandiedMango well, then you have to place 2 buttons, once the user enters a number, you will not do any post to backend,just with jquery add it to a list or variable on client side and show it in a label. Every time the user enters a number and clicks Add, you get the value and sort it and add it newely to the client variable. After the user finishes adding all his numbers, then he can click Save to send the data to the database

Comment: @alaa_sayegh That is initially what I wanted to do but I was unsure of how to get the data from the input box without sending it to the controller.

Comment: @CandiedMango, you don't need to send it initially to the controller. On a link click, crap the value that was entered and show it in a label. It is simple in JS. And after the user fnishes he will click Save and then now the label value (the sorted numbers) will be submitted to the server/db

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @CandiedMango let me post this as answer. do you need any code exmaple?

Comment: Code examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must store your data somewhere. For example you can store it in a session

> List numList = null;
>               int rNo = number.RNum;
>               string sequenceList = string.Empty;
>
> ```
>         if (Session["NumList"] != null)
>         {
>             //session exist. set numList = session
>             numList = Session["NumList"] as List<int>;
>         }
>         else {
>             //session not exist. set numList as new
>             numList = new List<int>();
>         }
>
>         //add number to numList
>         numList.Add(rNo);
>
>         //set session = numList
>         Session["NumList"] = numList;
>
>         //make join oj numList
>         sequenceList = String.Join(", ", numList.ToArray());
>         //set message in a ViewBag
>         ViewBag.Message = $"Number {rNo} saved successfully!" +
>             $" This is your current sequence : {sequenceList}" +
>             $" A total of {numList.Count} numbers.";
>
>         return View("Index");
> ```

I'm without Vs so can be errors

Answer (score 1):

You cannot retain these values in a controller variable. The Web is stateless, and each HTTP request executes a new instance of your code. So you'll need to persist your data somewhere.

You could utilize the **Session State** or **Application State** for that matter. For more reading:

- [ASP.NET Session State Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)
- [Session and Application states in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x)
- [Using ASP.NET MVC TempData and Session to pass values across Requests](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1074/aspnet-mvc-pass-values-temp-data-session-request)
- [Managing Controller Specific Session in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/manage-controller-specific-session-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/)

In a real-world application you'll definitely need a database storage. doesn't matter which store, you could use Sqlite, SQL Server, MySQL, XML documents or anything you want. If you're new to .NET Web Development I suggest you get started with **Entity Framework** for your data access needs. more information:

- [Entity Framework Tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/)
- [Introduction to Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [Entity Framework Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/)